# Auto delete row after 1 day wont work using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a remove the data row after a day ago using the following code.

```
mysqli_query($this->db,"DELETE FROM posts WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created)<=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

But it is deleting all rows everytime not 1 day ago. What I am doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: instead of `<=` try with `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Either use it on both sides of the comparison

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created)<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

or neither side

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE created<=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

*** Assuming `created` is a `DATE` type.*

Answer (score 2):

Since the `created` column is apparently already in seconds, to compare dates you should use `FROM_UNIXTIME(created)` rather than `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created)` in the MySQL query. See, for example: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-from_unixtime-function.php and compare with https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php.

If you want to delete all rows cleared a day ago, then the `WHERE` condition `<=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` condition is ok. But if you want to delete only rows cleared 1 day ago while keeping those that were created more than 1 day ago you would use `=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` instead.

All this assumes that the time zones for the dates being compared are set to be the same.